# Internet worked during install, but not after

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 beta 2 on my ASUS G55V and during install the internet (wireless) connected perfectly fine and downloaded updates.

After install, it was connected for a couple seconds until saying "disconnected"

It was still being recognized, but it would NOT connect.

I then looked online and seen people saying to add/remove things in

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

but I ended up screwing it up some more. I also ended up removing network manager as a whole as described online.

How do I get the internet working again? Neither wireless or ethernet work.

Comment: Try `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` and revert `/etc/network/interfaces` back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal do this:

```
sudo sh -c "cat > /etc/network/interfaces"
```

Now copy the following text:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Now restart your system and it should be back to normal.