# Every time 16.04 updates I must reinstall hplip

Tags: drivers, hp

Every time 16.04 updates I must reinstall hplip.  Is there a way to prevent this?  I am using a HP Officejet Pro 8100. Today is the 3rd time it happened.
I used both the repository and hp versions.  Today I used the repository again.

Comment: I applied an update this morning and the printer showed that hplip was missing.

Comment: Both.  This is an on going issue.  This time I used the repository.  Today is the 3rd time this happened.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit: 02/16/18:

The Ubuntu update problem that uninstalled unity and parts of desktop is now fixed.

### Original answer

Something wonky is going on with Ubuntu updates. It breaks  Unity and Ubuntu Desktop. To fix it you need `aptitude` which is not installed by default. Install aptitude by:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

If you fixed the problem by reinstalling `unity` by:

```
sudo aptitude install unity
```

Then there are a few things still broken including `hplip`. Use the command:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

This installed hplip for me among other things.

If you have not reinstalled unity first, then you can just use the second command to fix both the problems. In that case, remember to say no to the first solution (do nothing) proposed by aptitude, and yes to the second solution.

See [2/15/18 compiz update broke unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity)

for details.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've declined all updates since Jan 4, 2018 when the "wonkiness* began: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004796/install-ubuntu-including-all-drivers-from-the-usb-live-system/1006666#1006666 After six weeks with no more update errors reported I'll apply the upgrades. I've been manually installing 4.14.xx mainline/stable kernel updates as they have been release though and am currently on `4.14.18`.

Comment: OP appears to be running regular Kernel chain during Ubuntu Automatic Updates. My point was for myself I haven't run Automatic Updates since bugs started appearing January 4th 2018.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried installing unity and it said command does not exsist.  Oh well.  I going to go with my gut instinct and turn off updates.  Thats why I dumped windows.  The win 10 upgrade turned my computer into a brick.

Comment: You are welcome. You have to install `aptitude` first. I will update my answer. The issue with the updates is now sorted out.